# If we delete a Node from AVL tree and insert it back again, can we always get original tree? How?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

From a balanced AVL tree, if a Node is removed and insert it back, is it possible to get the original tree again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, No. Here's an example.

```
root: 10 
child_left: 5
child_right: 15
------------
15 as root
child_left: 12
child_right: 18
```

remove 10, you'll get something like

```
root: 12 
child_left: 5
child_right: 15
------------
15 as root
child_right: 18
```

Add 10, you'll get something like

```
root: 12 
child_left: 5
child_right: 15
------------
15 as root
child_left: 10
child_right: 18
------------
```

The last and first *can* be told same, but they're not exactly same, i suppose! If they can be told exactly same,  then it is possible to get the original tree again.